# How to escape accent letters in knit (R markdown)

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, rstudio, knitr

I'm trying to escape accent letters in knit like "ù". I use this letter inline, like in this exemple:
`df$comune <- ifelse(df$comune == "carru'", "carrù", df$comune)`.

The result is

[image: this]

You can see the last letter is not rendered properly and it stops rendering.
Thanks in advance for the help!

I tried:

- backslash (\)
- use backticks + backslash (`\)
- html encode char (ù)

edit:
I'm using the function for write r code and markdown on Rstudio.
You need to use ``` to open the section where you write code and again ``` to close it. When in this part i use "ù" (like in the photo) the function knit stops to render the html page

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Doesnt it work when you remove the '? As in "carru" instead of "carru'"?

Comment: the ' is not a problem, with it or without the result don't change

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
The problem was the encoding setted on RSTudio. Must set UTF-8